# Assign primary key to date type column in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am coding a program to track my finance. I have a table with several columns: Date, Flat, Food, Transport etc. I have assigned primary key to Date column since I thought it would be the unique one. Should have I done it differently? Maybe used int entryid or something?

Comment: you should use something except date

Comment: Don't pay your bills on the same day!

Answer (score 1):

It's practically always a good idea to use an auto-increment primary key.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

A `Date` field is not appropriate for a PK
of a table mostly because collisions may occur
(the presence of two records with the same `Date` value).